# Using Perl PCRE, I am having difficulty selecting and extracting text between keywords

Tags: regex

I am a Perl beginner. In the example shown below, I want to extract the text between the opening

```
<td valign=top>
```

and the first instance of the word "Plaintiff". I am missing something because I am unable to limit the capture. My attempts result in capturing the entire block.

I've looked at a number of questions and answers here, but quite honestly, I don't get what I am missing. It would seem to be an operator that would limit the capture, but I have not been able to figure out what operator it would be.

Jerry

```
<td valign=top><B>Any Name</B>  
<BRLaw Law Firm
<BR>11 East Wacker Drive
<BR>Suite 5759
<BR>Chicago, IL 60601
<BR>(312) 123-4567
<BR>LawyerName&#064;AnyLawFirm.com<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<I>Assigned: 12/04/2015</I><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<I>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</I></td>
<td>representing </td>
<td><B>Any Name</B>
<BR><I>(Plaintiff)</I></td>
</TR><td valign=top></td>
<td></td>
<td><B>Another Name </B>
<BR><I>(Plaintiff)</I></td>
</TR><td valign=top></td>
<td></td>
<td><B>Someones Name </B>
<BR><I>(Plaintiff)</I></td>
</TR><td valign=top><B>DefendantFirm</B>
<BR>Big Law Firm
<BR>214 West Monroe Street
<BR>Suite 7410
<BR>Chicago, IL 60606
<BR>(312) 456-7890
<BR>LitigastorName&#064;SomeLawOffice.com<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<I>Assigned: 11/22/2015</I><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<I>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</I></td>
<td>representing </td>
<td><B>DefendantFirm</B>
<BR><I>(Defendant)</I></td>
```

Comment: Is that enough: https://regex101.com/r/zH4cU3/2 ?

Comment: If you show us your attempt, we can tell you what you're missing. Most probably, it's a strategically placed `?`.

Comment: Do you want Plaintiff to show up in the block or not?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this regex expression can work:
    `<td valign=top>((\n|.)*?)Plaintiff`
Basically, we are matching `((\n|.)*?)`, which is a newline or any character beween `<td valign=top>` and `Plaintiff`. We are matching the least amount necessary when we put `*?`. The `*` allows infinite amount until we find it. The `?` looks the least amount it needs to to find it (The first occurrence).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the [`s` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers):

> s
>
> Treat string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

The `.` won't match a newline character (`\n`) unless you use it, so it is needed when attempting to use wildcards to span multiple lines.

You can use it thusly:

```
$ perl -00ne '/<td valign=top>.*?Plaintiff/s && print "$&"' file 
<td valign=top><B>Any Name</B>  
<BRLaw Law Firm
<BR>11 East Wacker Drive
<BR>Suite 5759
<BR>Chicago, IL 60601
<BR>(312) 123-4567
<BR>LawyerName&#064;AnyLawFirm.com<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<I>Assigned: 12/04/2015</I><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<I>ATTORNEY TO BE NOTICED</I></td>
<td>representing </td>
<td><B>Any Name</B>
<BR><I>(Plaintifft
```

The `-00` turns on paragraph mode. If this is part of a script and you have your input string in a variable, use this:

```
$var=~/<td valign=top>.*?Plaintiff/s;
print "$&\n";
```

If you only want the text between those two strings, excluding the strings themselves, you can capture it:

```
$var=~/<td valign=top>(.*?)Plaintiff/s;
print "$1\n";
```

Or use lookarounds:

```
$var=~/(?<=<td valign=top>).*?(?=Plaintiff)/s
print "$&\n";
```